# Access time for servers based in different countries

Tags: amazon-ec2

How much quicker would a page load if served from a EC2 EU server rather than a EC2 US server? if the request made form the UK?

I know this is the simplified scenario, but I am trying to establish whether it is worth the extra cost?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this question can be usefully answered, as there are so many imponderables; routing decisions change from second to second, latency in a routing device changes with the load on that device, and the US is quite wide.

The only concrete answer I ever give to questions like this is that the absolute lower-bound on round-trip time of a packet is the speed-of-light transit time from A to B and back.  The speed of light *in vacuo* is, near enough, 3x10^8 m/s, and in typical optical fibre, more like 2x10^8 m/s.  I advise you to work out the Great Circle distances from your position to the two hosting centres you are considering, double it, and work out the light transit times.

Your packet can never travel faster than that.  How much slower it will be is a nearly-theological question.